# How to get everything that inside tbody using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my html table: this is part of it

```
<tbody id="summaryBody">   
    <tr class="summaryRow">
        <td class="summaryPerson" colspan="2">   
            Super Man  
        </td>
        <td class="summaryFromDate">    
            11/21/2013   
        </td>
        <td class="summaryToDate">   
            11/21/2013  
        </td>
        <td class="summaryOriginalRecords">    
            1   
        </td>
        <td class="summaryOriginalHours">    
            2.00   
        </td>
        <td class="summaryExcludedHours">   
            0   
        </td>
        <td class="summaryTotalHours">   
            2.00   
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="summaryRow">
        <td class="summaryPerson" colspan="2"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryFromDate"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryToDate"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryOriginalRecords"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryOriginalHours"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryExcludedHours"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryTotalHours"> … </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="summaryRow">
        <td class="summaryPerson" colspan="2"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryFromDate"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryToDate"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryOriginalRecords"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryOriginalHours"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryExcludedHours"> … </td>
        <td class="summaryTotalHours"> … </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to get everything that is inside `tbody` element with all attributes and texts. How to do this using jquery?

I know only way when I can loop through each `tr`

```
$('tbody > tr').each()
```

but in this case I will need to select every attr and class and text and etc... It seems pretty hard. Is it any good way to get all elements? Maybe collection of `tr` element as text?

Help please=)

Comment: `$("#summaryBody").html()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the html contents of the `tbody` using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
var html = $('tbody').html();//using the id $('#summaryBody').html()
```

Comment: Thanks=) Looks like you were the first one, so I will accept your question... OMG... It's so easy=)

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple:

```
$("tbody").html();
```